# How to deploy an app to azure using ARM and C#?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-resource-manager

I've seen some examples of how to create storage resources using ARM and C#.  I'm assuming that the same is possible for apps.  However, I can't find a working example.
Ideally I'd like to have a c#/Web api app that would be able to deploy another app.  The process should be fully automated.
Basically, I'd like to create a new instance of the same app with its own configuration - the process would be triggered by a new customer signing up for my SaaS.
Could someone please give some pointers on how to deal with the above?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @bdristan, any updates? Are you able to manage Azure app service and deploy web application (deployment package) to Azure app service web app programmatically in  C# code now?

Comment: Hi Fred Han, I haven't gotten to it yet.  However, I think that solutions provided below will work for me.  I'll need to tackle the issue in about two months.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you’d like to deploy web application (deployment package) to Azure app service web app programmatically in C# code, you can try to use [Kudu Zip API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) that allows expanding zip files into folders. And the following sample code works fine for me, you can refer to it.

```
//get username and password from publish profile on Azure portal
var username = "xxxxx";
var password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var AppName = "{your_app_name}";

var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
var file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\xxx\xxx\WebApplication1.zip");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://{AppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl + "api/zip/site/wwwroot";
    var httpContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    var response = client.PutAsync(requestURl, httpContent).Result;
}
```

Besides, you can use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) to [manage your Azure app service](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-dotnet-manage-web-apps/blob/master/Program.cs).

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the Azure Management Libraries for .Net from Github. Support for Azure App Service is in preview as of v1.2. This enables a very intuitive syntax.

```
var webApp = azure.WebApps.Define(appName)
    .WithRegion(Region.USWest)
    .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
    .WithNewFreeAppServicePlan()
    .Create();
```

There are lots of code samples for both Windows and Linux flavours of Azure App Service shown here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent

There are also some worthwhile reading materials on how to handle data in this kind of scenario; various possibilities and design patterns are covered at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-patterns-multi-tenancy-saas-applications